How to access Files stored in OneDrive by an Android App
I have the need to write an App on an Android Tablet, to download Files stored in MicroSoft OneDrive. First of all I need to know whether it is possible or not. As a matter of fact, it exists an App, made by Microsoft itself, to access OneDrive from the tablet. So it should be possible, despite the App is made by Microsoft. But to write my own App I guess that an Api or Sdk should be used, if it exists.
Thanks for any hint.
Any hint may be useful, even if done in C#. In fact I am also thinking that, if not directly possible, to write a WebService allowing to download the files to my server and then making them reachable from the Android App. But of course, this should be the second chance.
